# USB install 20.04 location of recovery id?

Tags: security, data-recovery, usb-installation

I hope everyone and their loved ones are healthy and happy.

When doing an Ubuntu 20.04 USB install with LUKS encryption and LVM, as the install onto the hard drive completes, a message appears that lists the location of the recovery ID. It states your recovery id is located in /home/ubuntu/release

So here's the question: Because of how and when it appears, it's unclear if that message refers to to the new install or in the system running off the USB stick.

I assumed it would be located in the new install. So I completed the installation and lo and behold, there is no recover ID anywhere in the new install.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: The message indicated that the file named `release` is located in the home folder for the "ubuntu" user (`/home/ubuntu`). The "ubuntu" user is the default user id for the Live ISO Environment. (In contrast, if the file had hypothetically been placed in the home folder for your newly created user, the path displayed would have been different. For example, it may have said `/home/jeffschips`. However, it looks like the installer does not do this.)

Comment: I suppose this installation was done with LVM and LUKs encryption and the recovery ID relates to the LUKs encryption. This is not clear from the question. Please [edit the question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1362397/edit) and clarify this point. The default installation process does not generate any recovery ID.

Comment: My apologies - LVM and luks encryption.